# Make material design layout appear fullscreen

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, material-design

I'm starting to learn Ruby on Rails and therefor coding a little website. I'm also new to frontend development.

I tried to implement the sidebar and header via Rails application.html.erb where I think the problem occurs. I used a google material design template (http://www.getmdl.io/templates/dashboard/index.html).

As you can see in the screenshot, the problem is that most of the body is white. The strange thing is that after you refresh the page, everything gets shown correctly.

Thanks for your help!

Here is my code so far:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="A front-end template that helps you build fast, modern mobile web apps.">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

        <title>HouseholdBook</title>

        <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android -->
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/android-desktop.png">

        <!-- Add to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Material Design Lite">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/ios-desktop.png">

        <!-- Tile icon for Win8 (144x144 + tile color) -->
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/touch/ms-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#3372DF">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">

        <style>
            #view-source {
                position: fixed;
                display: block;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                margin-right: 40px;
                margin-bottom: 40px;
                z-index: 900;
            }

        </style>

        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="demo-layout mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer mdl-layout--fixed-header">
            <header class="demo-header mdl-layout__header mdl-color--grey-100 mdl-color-text--grey-600">
                <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
                    <span id="headerLabel" class="mdl-layout-title">Home</span>
                    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable">
                        <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="search">
                            <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                        </label>
                        <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="search">
                            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="search">Enter your query...</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--icon" id="hdrbtn">
                        <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-menu--bottom-right" for="hdrbtn">
                        <li class="mdl-menu__item">About</li>
                        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Contact</li>
                        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Legal information</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="demo-drawer mdl-layout__drawer mdl-color--blue-grey-900 mdl-color-text--blue-grey-50">
                <header class="demo-drawer-header">
                    <%= image_tag("user.jpg", :class =>"demo-avatar")%>
                    <div class="demo-avatar-dropdown">
                        <span>hello@example.com</span>
                        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                        <button id="accbtn" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--icon">
                            <i class="material-icons" role="presentation">arrow_drop_down</i>
                            <span class="visuallyhidden">Accounts</span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="accbtn">
                            <li class="mdl-menu__item">hello@example.com</li>
                            <li class="mdl-menu__item">info@example.com</li>
                            <li class="mdl-menu__item">
                                <i class="material-icons">add</i>Add another account...</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </header>
                <nav class="demo-navigation mdl-navigation mdl-color--blue-grey-800">
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="<%=root_path%>">
                        <i class="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">home</i>Home</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="<%=items_path%>">
                        <i class="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">list</i>Übersicht</a>
                    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">
                        <i class="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">help_outline</i>
                        <span class="visuallyhidden">Help</span>
                    </a>
                </nav>
            </div>

            <main class="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100">
                <%= yield %>
            </main>
        </div>

        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" style="position: fixed; left: -1000px; height: -1000px;">
            <defs>
                <mask id="piemask" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                    <circle cx=0.5 cy=0.5 r=0.49 fill="white"/>
                    <circle cx=0.5 cy=0.5 r=0.40 fill="black"/>
                </mask>
                <g id="piechart">
                    <circle cx=0.5 cy=0.5 r=0.5/>
                    <path d="M 0.5 0.5 0.5 0 A 0.5 0.5 0 0 1 0.95 0.28 z" stroke="none" fill="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)"/>
                </g>
            </defs>
        </svg>
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 250" style="position: fixed; left: -1000px; height: -1000px;">
            <defs>
                <g id="chart">
                    <g id="Gridlines">
                        <line fill="#888888" stroke="#888888" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="0" y1="27.3" x2="468.3" y2="27.3"/>
                        <line fill="#888888" stroke="#888888" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="0" y1="66.7" x2="468.3" y2="66.7"/>
                        <line fill="#888888" stroke="#888888" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="0" y1="105.3" x2="468.3" y2="105.3"/>
                        <line fill="#888888" stroke="#888888" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="0" y1="144.7" x2="468.3" y2="144.7"/>
                        <line fill="#888888" stroke="#888888" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="0" y1="184.3" x2="468.3" y2="184.3"/>
                    </g>
                    <g id="Numbers">
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 485 29.3333)" fill="#888888" font-family="'Roboto'" font-size="9">500</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 485 69)" fill="#888888" font-family="'Roboto'" font-size="9">400</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 485 109.3333)" fill="#888888" font-family="'Roboto'" font-size="9">300</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 485 149)" fill="#888888" font-family="'Roboto'" font-size="9">200</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 485 188.3333)" fill="#888888" font-family="'Roboto'" font-size="9">100</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 249.0003)" fill="#888888" font-family="'Roboto'" font-size="9">1</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 78 249.0003)" fill="#888888" font-family="'Roboto'" font-size="9">2</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 154.6667 249.0003)" fill="#888888" font-family="'Roboto'" font-size="9">3</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 232.1667 249.0003)" fill="#888888" font-family="'Roboto'" font-size="9">4</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 309 249.0003)" fill="#888888" font-family="'Roboto'" font-size="9">5</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 386.6667 249.0003)" fill="#888888" font-family="'Roboto'" font-size="9">6</text>
                        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 464.3333 249.0003)" fill="#888888" font-family="'Roboto'" font-size="9">7</text>
                    </g>
                    <g id="Layer_5">
                        <polygon opacity="0.36" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="0,223.3 48,138.5 154.7,169 211,88.5
                294.5,80.5 380,165.2 437,75.5 469.5,223.3   "/>
                    </g>
                    <g id="Layer_4">
                        <polygon stroke-miterlimit="10" points="469.3,222.7 1,222.7 48.7,166.7 155.7,188.3 212,132.7
                296.7,128 380.7,184.3 436.7,125     "/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </defs>
        </svg>
        <a href="https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/master/templates/dashboard/" target="_blank" id="view-source" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-color-text--white">View Source</a>
        <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

[Half the screen is white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B1BL.png)

Comment: What do you mean after "refreshing the page everything is shown correctly"? The issue only occurs if you navigate directly to the URL?

Comment: Yes if I visit the page via url its messed up. The same goes for links that navigate through the page. Its correct after I hit refresh.

Comment: @NiclasC. See if removing the Turbolinks gem helps.

Comment: @maxpleaner That did indeed help but after the page is loaded I get the exact same white screen but only for a milli second until the page is fully loaded. `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>` is the line code I removed.

Comment: @NiclasC. maybe try removing the gem from Gemfile and the `require` line in application.js

Comment: @maxpleaner That did help but again the page shows the white space until the page is fully loaded (it just flashes for a second). I assume that the main problem is somewhere else.

Comment: That sounds like the way a web page typically loads. As the elements (images, etc) get loaded, the pages changes to accomodate them.